# A translator per language in LinguaPlone

Tags: plone, linguaplone

I want to have a group in Plone that can only translate for 1 specific language. Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Use case is that there are quite a bit of languages in a site, and that the translators can only translate for their language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without very substantial customization. With some code added, you could make the translate drop-down actions smarter, so that they only offered particular languages to users from particular groups. That might give you what you need.

If you need security to match, it would be harder. You'd have to intervene (via code) after translation creation to set sharing.

So, *possible* yes. *Practical*, probably not.

If this is a very high priority project, and you have resources available, get in touch with the folks working on the next generation of LinguaPlone, and offer to help develop (or to fund development) for the feature. That might be the very best way to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I think I will try to make the dropdown actions smarter.

Answer (score 2):

Actually — this doesn't have to be so hard.

By granting the translator add and edit permissions in the required language subfolder, and not in the other language subtrees, this should all simply work.

The only real need for customisation might be to hide the translate actions from the menu if the user doesn't have permissions to translate to there.

Comment: I tried this, if a user only has view rights to f/e /en/ not edit or add, he or she can still translate the page with the submenu.
I'm going to try and change the actions menu (when I can find it) and I will probably add the rights as well.